# How do I add numbers one after the other

Tags: javascript

I tried to add the numbers one after the other.

For example, if the number was 10 and then 4 the output would be 14.

```
let getPlayer2Value = document.querySelector(".getValueP2")
getPlayer2Value.addEventListener("click", init);

function init() {    
  window.roundScore = 0;
  window.diceValue =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  window.player2Score = document.querySelector(".totalScoreP2");

  getPlayer2Value.addEventListener("click", () =>
  {
    roundScore += dice;
    player2Score.innerHTML = roundScore;
  });
}
```

Comment: You reset `window.roundScore` to `0` each time the click event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

`firstNumber += secondNumber`

or

`firstNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber`

You're already useing `+=` but I think you have a typo. It should be `diceValue` not `dice`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that you'll have to separate the `init()` that sets `roundScore = 0` from the event that triggers the adding of numbers one after another. Otherwise, you're constantly setting it to zero. See the snippet below for example:

```js
let initializer = document.querySelector(".init");
let player2Score = document.querySelector(".totalScoreP2");
let getPlayer2Value = document.querySelector(".getValueP2");

let roundScore;

function init() {
  roundScore = 0;
  player2Score.innerHTML = roundScore;
  explanation.innerHTML = `init clicked, roundScore = 0`;
}

getPlayer2Value.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let diceValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  explanation.innerHTML = `${roundScore} (previous roundScore) + ${diceValue} (diceValue)`;
  roundScore += diceValue;
  player2Score.innerHTML = roundScore;
});

initializer.addEventListener("click", init);
```

```html
<button class="init">Init</button>
<button class="getValueP2">getValueP2</button>
<div class="totalScoreP2"></div>
<small id="explanation"></small>
```